# How to get filtered vm size list by susbcription id and location in Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to list the available sizes for a zone, it returns all the sizes but I need to filter them by the ones available for subscription. Unfortunately I can't find a way to do it with the python SDK. Is there a way to do it?

I am using the package `azure.mgmt.compute` with `ComputeManagementClient`, then I use the method `virtual_machines_sizes.list(location=location)` and get all sizes available for this location, but not filtered by susbcription ID because my subscription has 10 vcpu limit.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Python API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.operations.virtualmachinesizesoperations?view=azure-python#list-location----kwargs-), it looks like the `list` API is deprecated (corresponding Azure SDK for Python source [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/compute/azure-mgmt-compute/azure/mgmt/compute/v2020_06_01/operations/_virtual_machine_sizes_operations.py#L48)). The [Resource SKUs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list) is the suggested alternative.

So you can use the [list()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_09_01.operations.resourceskusoperations?view=azure-python#list---kwargs-) method from the **ResourceSkusOperations class** with your `compute_client` to get the list of `Microsoft.Compute` SKUs available for your Subscription.